# How to create hover effect in html table using css?

Tags: html, css

i tried creating a hover effect using css, where if the user hovers through the table's rows, it will change the background-color to red. But i notice when i hover the rows, instead of filling up the whole row with red, it fills up only the individual cells.

Here is my code:

```css
.GridviewScrollHeader TH,
.GridviewScrollHeader TD {
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: left;
}

.GridviewScrollItem TD {
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.GridviewScrollItem TD:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>
    Test
  </title>

  <link href="GridviewScroll.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style type="text/css">
    BODY,
    TD {
      font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Verdana;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #333333;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellspacing="0" id="GridView1" style="width:100%;border-
    collapse:collapse;">
    <tr class="GridviewScrollHeader">
      <td colspan="2">Product</td>
      <td rowspan="2">ListPrice</td>
      <td rowspan="2">StandardCost</td>
      <td colspan="2">Package</td>
      <td rowspan="2">SafetyStockLevel</td>
      <td rowspan="2">ReorderPoint</td>
      <td rowspan="2">SellStartDate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridviewScrollHeader">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Weight</td>
      <td>Size</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridviewScrollItem">
      <td>HL Mountain Frame - Black, 38</td>
      <td>FR-M94B-38</td>
      <td>1349.6000</td>
      <td>739.0410</td>
      <td>2.68</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>375</td>
      <td>7/1/2005 12:00:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridviewScrollItem">
      <td>HL Mountain Frame - Silver, 38</td>
      <td>FR-M94S-38</td>
      <td>1364.5000</td>
      <td>747.2002</td>
      <td>2.68</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>375</td>
      <td>7/1/2005 12:00:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens, because you set the Hover Effect only to the td elements, not the whole row. If you remove the `td` from your css and only apply the hover to the `tr` Elements, it works.

**Note**: You have to remove the specific background color of the `td` Elements, because they would override the `tr:hover` effect. Please take a look at the working snippet below.

```css
.GridviewScrollHeader th, .GridviewScrollHeader td {
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
}

.GridviewScrollItem TD {
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

.GridviewScrollItem {
  background: #fff;
}

.GridviewScrollItem:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" id="GridView1" style="width:100%;border-
collapse:collapse;">
    <tr class="GridviewScrollHeader">
        <td colspan="2">Product</td>
        <td rowspan="2">ListPrice</td>
        <td rowspan="2">StandardCost</td>
        <td colspan="2">Package</td>
        <td rowspan="2">SafetyStockLevel</td>
        <td rowspan="2">ReorderPoint</td>
        <td rowspan="2">SellStartDate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridviewScrollHeader">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>Weight</td>
        <td>Size</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridviewScrollItem">
        <td>HL Mountain Frame - Black, 38</td>
        <td>FR-M94B-38</td>
        <td>1349.6000</td>
        <td>739.0410</td>
        <td>2.68</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>375</td>
        <td>7/1/2005 12:00:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridviewScrollItem">
        <td>HL Mountain Frame - Silver, 38</td>
        <td>FR-M94S-38</td>
        <td>1364.5000</td>
        <td>747.2002</td>
        <td>2.68</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>375</td>
        <td>7/1/2005 12:00:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your hovering css to below code.

```
.GridviewScrollItem:hover TD
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Please check this **[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kitcodes/Lb03mspe/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the hover to whole **table row** means your `tr`, now you have only to your `td`

Just add **hover** to your **row**:

```
.GridviewScrollItem:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```css
.GridviewScrollHeader th, .GridviewScrollHeader td {
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
}

.GridviewScrollItem TD {
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

.GridviewScrollItem {
  background: #fff;
}

.GridviewScrollItem:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" id="GridView1" style="width:100%;border-
collapse:collapse;">
    <tr class="GridviewScrollHeader">
        <td colspan="2">Product</td>
        <td rowspan="2">ListPrice</td>
        <td rowspan="2">StandardCost</td>
        <td colspan="2">Package</td>
        <td rowspan="2">SafetyStockLevel</td>
        <td rowspan="2">ReorderPoint</td>
        <td rowspan="2">SellStartDate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridviewScrollHeader">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>Weight</td>
        <td>Size</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridviewScrollItem">
        <td>HL Mountain Frame - Black, 38</td>
        <td>FR-M94B-38</td>
        <td>1349.6000</td>
        <td>739.0410</td>
        <td>2.68</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>375</td>
        <td>7/1/2005 12:00:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridviewScrollItem">
        <td>HL Mountain Frame - Silver, 38</td>
        <td>FR-M94S-38</td>
        <td>1364.5000</td>
        <td>747.2002</td>
        <td>2.68</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>375</td>
        <td>7/1/2005 12:00:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I tried is different and may have some issues but I cant say I didnt try I do see better results from others :)

CSS:

```
.GridviewScrollHeader TH, .GridviewScrollHeader TD{
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
}

.GridviewScrollItem TD{
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* The :nth-child() Does not work on some versions of IE 
removing it will only let you highlight other fields there on until the end of the "td" 
just add overflow-x:hidden if you remove the nth child and make the table full screen width by setting body margin to 0*/

.GridviewScrollItem TD:nth-child(1):hover{
    background-color: red;
    width:98.4%; /* If you ever Change the margins make sure to change this accordingly */ /* full screen is 100% but take note of margins */
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0.5; /* Does not work in IE9 or less */ /* Check for other opacity attributes for older IE Browsers */
    font-weight:bold; /* To Darken text to still be visable */
}
```

The HTML hasn't changed and it does seem to rely on opacity but this is my results some of you may disagree.